# How to know which anchor is clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="document_dropdown">
    <li><a class="notify" href="toSomewhere" id="1">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a class="notify" href="toSomewhere" id="2">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a class="notify" href="toSomewhere" id="3">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a class="notify" href="toSomewhere" id="4">Item1</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#document_dropdown .notify').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

What I want to achieve is to see which anchor is clicked and return the id of that anchor so that I can use it in another script. So far it doesn't do anything. What might be wrong with my code? Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have will work fine, although `this.id` is a more succinct method of retrieving a native property from an element. If you wish to stop the clicking of the link causing the browser to make an HTTP request, you would need to add `preventDefault()` to your logic.

You cannot return anything from an event handler, so instead if you need to pass information around you would need to either store it in a global variable, or call another function with that value as a parameter.

```
$('#document_dropdown .notify').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
    doSomething(id);
});

function doSomething(id) {
    alert('You clicked #' + id);   
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1jsxo5rt/)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#document_dropdown .notify').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Thats it.

Comment: This is logically no different from what the OP is already doing, except he's using the `id` property of the jQuery object instead of the native element reference in `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler cannot return anything. You need to call another script function and pass the ID as as argument.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#document_dropdown .notify').click(function(evt){
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
   anotherScriptFunction(id);
   evt.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: thanks. but it still redirects to the page in href even with preventDefault() is there.

Comment: then just add href 
<a class="notify"href="javascript:void(0)" id="1">Item1</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the event handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#document_dropdown .notify').click(function(e){
        var id = e.target.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

In this way, `e.target` is the element you have clicked on. You can wrapper it into a jQuery element through `$(e.target)`.